# Preventing Reset during ESD

Tags: remote-control, esd, reset

I would like to design a RC filter to prevent reset to a SoC during a ESD strike. Assuming the reset net is by default low.

And the reset comes from a separate board which connects to the main board (where SoC resides) using a Board to Board connector.

In case there is air discharge on the daughter board. I want to avoid changing the state of reset line during the ESD strike and avoid trigger of reset to the SoC.

Comment: I don't see a question here. Before you can design a filter you need to know what exactly you are filtering out, and what you need to leave in (if you don't need to leave anything in, there is no need for a connection).

Comment: Please provide more information. To prevent reset to what?

Comment: I want to prevent reset in case is there an ESD strike on that particular net.

Comment: You haven't told us what it is you are trying to protect. Is it a computer, an MCU in a microwave oven, a digital clock, a circuit breaker, the electronic odometer in a car, a power sub station? You haven't explained how the ESD might get in. Is it from walking across a nylon carpet, a piezo ignition on a cooker, a lightening strike, a nylon comb poked into an ethernet socket?

Comment: I though avoiding changing of digital states  during ESD strike is a typical condition so I chose to share less details. Please let me know if you need more details. Apology for my presumptuousness @gbulmer

Comment: I was only trying to help get a clear question so you get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the reset pin is pulled up, putting a 100nF cap to ground at the pin generally won't hurt you. The bigger issue here is ESD protection. Where is the ESD getting into the circuit? Cable shields, connectors, the enclosure, any user interface buttons or knobs, , etc. all need to be considered. The energy from the event needs to be safely dissipated, with the how depending on the source. I strongly recommend read through [John Barnes' articles](http://www.dbicorporation.com/esd-art1.htm) on ESD protection.